# Exporting via CDF

Tags: export, cdf-format, deployment, cdfplayer, wolfram-player

I want to simply use a CDF deploy to export a text file onto the notebook directory

```
CDFDeploy["ExportCDF",
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
Button["Export", Export["new.txt", 1]]];
```

But this does not seem to work with the Wolfram Player. Are there any `CDFDeploy` options to make it work?

Comment: Export is disabled in a FreePlayer, see "Export live data/files (all formats)" in https://www.wolfram.com/cdf/adopting-cdf/cdf-and-mathematica-comparison.html

Comment: I think you're limited to `CopyToClipBoard` as far as exporting information.

Comment: @JimB What about editing a text file? A guess that would require importing it somehow.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding the question.  If you have a text editor open you can paste stuff into a text file and then edit.   As noted by @Kuba, exporting is pretty limited in the Wolfram Player (formerly CDF Player).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a work version: use player to open a cdf file, then click the button to export file.

```
Button["Export", Export["/tmp/new.txt", 1]]
```

server code:

```
WolframPlayer[box_] := {
        "wolframplayer",
        Export[FileNameJoin@{$TemporaryOutput, CreateUUID["CDFOutput-"]<>".cdf"}, Notebook[{Cell@BoxData@ToBoxes@box}, WindowSize -> All], "CDF"],
        "&"
} // StringRiffle // Run
request["Body"] // ToExpression[#, StandardForm]& // WolframPlayer;
```

effect

[image]

full code is here:

https://github.com/asukaminato0721/mmaplayer/blob/master/server.wls